# How to create <html>, <head> and <body> if they don't exist in an HTML?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, webkit, webview

When I load an HTML in a WebView, and the HTML has explicit `<head>` and `<body>`, I can get the head and insert a link to inject some CSS styles to the document on the fly.
I also manipulate the DOM on the body.
But what do I do when the HTML doesn't have this tags defined?
I can't modify the HTML file as it's user-provided.
I tried `[DOMDocument createElement:]` and `[DOMDocument appendChild:]` to insert a html, a head and a body, but didn't work.
How should this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could read the contents of the DOMDocument into an NSMutableString and append it then before loading the web view from this string...